# Android and Spring Cloud Eureka Service Registration

Tags: android, spring-cloud, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I'm writing an Android app that calls microservices written with Spring Boot.  We're working to integrate Eureka for service discovery and move to a cloud native architecture.

I've read a lot of documentation about how to use Eureka in Spring client calls.  However we're writing a native Android app without Spring.

What are my options to use service discovery?  Do I need to use an API gateway or is there another way?

Comment: Ideally you would use an API gateway of some sort.  If your Android native client is making many remote calls to Eureka + other microservices, there would be many opportunities for something to go wrong.  Losing or changing networks being the big one that comes to mind.

Comment:  Your android client should never interact with eureka. It's purely a server side concern.

Comment: If I want to deploy my own API gateway solution, how would I avoid a single point of failure on the gateway?  How could I distribute the API gateway across multiple servers and let the client know about the location?  I'm assuming a 3rd party solution (i.e. apigee) would take care of this for me.